# How do I display text to respective div container on hover with JS or Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to show the text that is within the div property when the mouse hovers over it. I have three div boxes and three texts in each box. I know I can accomplish this by CSS only but I am new to coding and am trying to learn JS and Jquery better.

I was practising with pure JS and at first, and I could only make the first box show on hover but not the others two and when I printed out the vars, to the console, I noticed it was only pulling the first elements of the divs, that's when I switched to .querySelectorAll to get all three elements but now I don't know how to use either this/event.target/event.currentTarget. I'm assuming that's what I would use to get the targeted element to show up but I don't know how to use them.

```js
let text = document.querySelectorAll('a div');
let pic = document.querySelectorAll('.boxcontainer a')


pic.addEventListener("mouseenter", function() {
  this.style.visibility = 'visible';

});

pic.addEventListener("mouseleave", function() {
  this.style.visibility = 'hidden';
});
```

```css
.boxcontainer {
  width: 30%;
  height: 50%;
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  z-index: 100;
}

.boxcontainer a {
  box-shadow: -9px 12px 7px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.336);
  margin: 10px;
  padding-top: 10%;
  padding-bottom: 10%;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.boxcontainer a:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  color: white;
}

#text {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxcontainer">

  <a href="asia.html" style="background-color:#46515a;">
    <div id='text'>asia.</div>
  </a>
  <a href="americas.html" style="background-color: #2d343a;">
    <div id='text'>americas.</div>
  </a>
  <a href="europe.html" style="background-color: #1a1f22;">
    <div id='text'>europe.</div>
  </a>

</div>
```

Comment: Since `querySelectorAll()` returns a HTMLCollection you have to add the eventlistener to each element in the collection. Usually by using a for-loop. Currently you are trying to call `addEventListener` to a Collection-Object and not the elements itself. Furthermore you could check out the html attribute `title` or the css function `attr()` to achieve your goal without JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Immediate problem I can see is that you have 3 divs with the same id. Id should be unique. Change id it to class and change your javascript reference to class:

`let text = document.querySelectorAll(".text");`

Comment: The wrong use of ID vs Class is not actually the problem with the code. See my answer for the reason the code does not work. Someone seems to have felt I tried to steal your answer by including the fact that IDs need to be unique. That was not my intention, in case you wondered

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer, thank you for anyone who helped

jQuery

```
  $('.text').hide();

     $(".boxcontainer a").on('mouseenter', function() {

     $(this).find('.text').fadeIn(300);
     });

     $(".boxcontainer a").on('mouseleave',function() {

     $(this).find('.text').hide();
     });
```

HTML

```
     <div class="boxcontainer">

                    <a href="asia.html" style="background-color:#46515a;"> <div class = 'text'>asia.</div></a> 
                    <a href="americas.html" style="background-color: #2d343a;"> <div class='text'>americas.</div></a>
                    <a href="europe.html" style="background-color: #1a1f22;"><div class='text'>europe.</div></a>

            </div>
```

CSS

```
.boxcontainer{
    width: 30%;
    height: 50%;
    position: fixed;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    z-index: 100;
}

.boxcontainer a{
    box-shadow: -9px 12px 7px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.336);
    margin: 10px;
    padding-top: 10%;
    padding-bottom: 10%;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;


}

.boxcontainer a:hover{
    transform: scale(1.1);
    color: white;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You are using jQuery functionality on DOM access.

You cannot mouseover hidden stuff so my answer moves the divs out of the  anchors.

As J Doe pointed out, the text ID should be changed to class since IDs need to be unique - this has no bearing on the actual issue though

Here is the vanilla version - I would normally delegate but in this case we need an eventListener on each link

```js
const overAndOut = e => {
  const tgt = e.target; 
  if (tgt.tagName === "A") {
    tgt.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('text', e.type === "mouseleave")
  }
};
[...document.querySelectorAll('#boxcontainer a')].forEach(link => {
  link.addEventListener('mouseover', overAndOut)
  link.addEventListener('mouseleave', overAndOut)
})
```

```css
.boxcontainer {
  width: 30%;
  height: 50%;
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  z-index: 100;
}

.boxcontainer a {
  box-shadow: -9px 12px 7px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.336);
  margin: 10px;
  padding-top: 10%;
  padding-bottom: 10%;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.boxcontainer a:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  color: white;
}

.text {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="boxcontainer">

  <a href="asia.html" style="background-color:#46515a;">Asia</a>
  <div class='text'>asia.</div>
  <a href="americas.html" style="background-color: #2d343a;">Americas</a>
  <div class='text'>Americas.</div>
  <a href="europe.html" style="background-color: #1a1f22;">Europe</a>
  <div class='text'>Europe.</div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```js
$('#boxcontainer a').on("mouseenter", function() {
    $(this).next().removeClass("text")
  })
  .on("mouseleave", function() {
    $(this).next().addClass("text")
  });
```

```css
.boxcontainer {
  width: 30%;
  height: 50%;
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  z-index: 100;
}

.boxcontainer a {
  box-shadow: -9px 12px 7px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.336);
  margin: 10px;
  padding-top: 10%;
  padding-bottom: 10%;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.boxcontainer a:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  color: white;
}

.text {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="boxcontainer">
  <a href="asia.html" style="background-color:#46515a;">Asia</a>
  <div class='text'>Asia.</div>

  <a href="americas.html" style="background-color: #2d343a;">Americas</a>
  <div class='text'>Americas.</div>

  <a href="europe.html" style="background-color: #1a1f22;">Europe</a>
  <div class='text'>Europe.</div>

</div>
```